# Agregar input file dentro de un campo tipo tabla de Backpack For Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, backpack-for-laravel

Una funcionalidad requerida necesita agregar varias entradas en una tabla. Por lo que agregué el siguiente campo mi `ModelCrudController`:

```
$this->crud->addField([
'name'            => 'cookware_variants',
'label'           => 'Variants',
'type'            => 'table_with_image',
'entity_singular' => 'variant', // used on the "Add X" button
'columns'         => [
    'name'  => 'Variant name',
    'details'  => 'Variant details',
    'image'  => 'Variant image'
],
'max' => 10, // maximum rows allowed in the table
'min' => 1, // minimum rows allowed in the table

// Tabs fields
'tab'      => 'Tab',
'fake'     => true, // show the field, but don't store it in the database column above
// 'store_in' => 'details' // [optional] the database column name where you want the fake fields to ACTUALLY be stored as a JSON array 
]);
```

El campo `table` existe en `Backpack`, solamente creé uno nuevo, con base en el original y modifiqué esta parte para que, en vez de crear todos los campos tipo texto, dependiendo la llave, añada uno tipo `file`.

```
<tr class="array-row clonable" style="display: none;">
@foreach( $field['columns'] as $column => $label)
@if($column == "image")
<td>
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="file" accept="image/*" data-cell-name="item.{{ $column }}">
</td>
@else
<td>
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" data-cell-name="item.{{ $column }}">
</td>
@endif
@endforeach
<td>
    <span class="btn btn-sm btn-light sort-handle pull-right"><span class="sr-only">sort item</span><i class="la la-sort" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
</td>
<td>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-light removeItem" type="button"><span class="sr-only">delete item</span><i class="la la-trash" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</td>
```

El código visualmente funciona:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando mando el `request` no manda nada relativo al `input file` que anadí, solo manda la información de los `input text`. Esta la salida de un `dd($this->crud->getRequest()->request);`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aún no he encontrado la forma para que estos `input file` aparezcan en el `request` para poder manipularlos y guardarlos apropiadamente.

Las versiones de `Laravel` y `Backpack For Laravel (Con licencia)` son:

```
"php": "^8.0.2"
"backpack/crud": "^5.4"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que hay que hacer, como lo indico en la misma pregunta es obtener el archivo del campo:

```
php artisan backpack:field --from=table
```

Después hay que modificar el nombre del archivo por algo como `table_with_image.blade.php`. Solamente para no poder seguir usando el campo `table` normalmente en otros lados.

Mandar llamar este campo en el `field` con el `type => 'table_with_image'`.

Ahora empezaremos a modificar el archivo `table_with_image.blade.php` en la parte del `<tbody>`, explicaré cada modificación en los comentarios:

```html
<tbody class="table-striped items sortableOptions">

    <!-- Detectar si existen valores para saber si se está editando o creando -->
    @if(isset($field['value']))
        <tr class="array-row clonable" style="display: none;">
            
            @foreach( $field['columns'] as $column => $label)
                @if($column == 'image') <!-- Si la columna que se está agregando es nuestro espacio deseado para la imagen -->
                    <td> <!-- Hay que crear un input disabled para después manejarlos en JS, agregarle la clase variant-image para control -->
                        <input disabled class="form-control form-control-sm variant-image" type="text" data-cell-name="item.{{ $column }}">
                    </td>
                @else <!-- Campo normal de texto que ya viene por defecto -->
                    <td>
                        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" data-cell-name="item.{{ $column }}">
                    </td>
                @endif
            @endforeach


            <td>
                <span class="btn btn-sm btn-light sort-handle pull-right"><span class="sr-only">sort item</span><i class="la la-sort" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-light removeItem" type="button"><span class="sr-only">delete item</span><i class="la la-trash" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </td>
        </tr>

    @else
        <tr class="array-row clonable" style="display: none;">
            
            @foreach( $field['columns'] as $column => $label)
                @if($column == "image")<!-- Si la columna que se está agregando es nuestro espacio deseado para la imagen -->
                    <td> <!-- Si estamos creando una entrada nueva, hay que poner un input file con el name terminando en [] para tener todos los archivos con el mismp nombre -->
                        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="file" accept="image/*" data-cell-name="item.{{ $column }}" name="item.{{ $column }}[]">
                    </td>
                @else
                    <td> <!-- Campo normal de texto que ya viene por defecto -->
                        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" data-cell-name="item.{{ $column }}">
                    </td>
                @endif
            @endforeach


            <td>
                <span class="btn btn-sm btn-light sort-handle pull-right"><span class="sr-only">sort item</span><i class="la la-sort" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-light removeItem" type="button"><span class="sr-only">delete item</span><i class="la la-trash" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endif
</tbody>
```

Y ahora, justo encima de la línea `@endpush` colocamos nuestro script:

```js
<script>

    // Función para crear inputs necesarios para agregar un nuevo archivo o guardar el valor actual del campo
    function createFileInput(hidden = false, named = true, value = null) {
        let input = document.createElement('input');
        if (hidden) {
            input.type = "hidden";
            if (value) {
                input.value = value;
            } else {
                input.value = 'NA';
            }
        } else {
            input.setAttribute('data-dummy', 'true');
            input.type = "file";
        }
        if (named) {
            input.name = "item.image[]";
        }
        input.accept = "image/*";
        input.setAttribute('data-cell-name', 'item.image');
        input.classList.add('form-control');
        input.classList.add('form-control-sm');
        return input;
    }

    // Función para crear las filas de la tabla
    function createImageColumns() {

        // Obtenemos los campos por medio de la clase de control que agregamos más arriba
        let variant_fields = document.querySelectorAll('.variant-image');

        // Esto era para quitar el primer element que era un clonable que hace Backpack por defecto, pero al final no lo quité y puse 0 para que no quitara ningún elemento
        // Puedes ser nodes = variant_fields
        let nodes = [].slice.call(variant_fields, 0);

        for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {

            // Obtener el div padre de la columna
            let parent = nodes[i].parentElement;

            // Verificar si no es el elemento clonable que hace Backpack por defecto
            if (!parent.closest('tr').classList.contains('clonable')) {

                // Aplicar un estilo y agregar un dataset de control para el indice de fila
                parent.style.width = '35%';
                parent.setAttribute('data-index', i);

                // Obtener la ruta de la imagen si es que existe una y eliminar el nodo
                let img_route = nodes[i].value;
                nodes[i].remove();

                // Si la imagen existe 
                if (img_route == null || img_route == undefined || img_route === 'NA') { // NA es control propio

                    // Crear un file input y uno más hidden input para ponérselos al div padre
                    let input = createFileInput();
                    // True #1 porque no hay valor y necesito un hidden para controlar con 'NA' como vacío
                    // True #2 porque necesito que se agregue el attributo nombre para tomarlo después en el request
                    let input_hidden = createFileInput(true, true); 
                    parent.appendChild(input);
                    parent.appendChild(input_hidden);

                } else {

                    // Si existe un valor válido como imagen...

                    // Creamos un contenedor general
                    let image_container = document.createElement('div');

                    // Creamos una imagen y le ponemos su attributo src
                    let image = document.createElement('img');
                    image.src = img_route;

                    // Un botón si desean ver la imagen más grande en otra pestaña
                    let view_button = document.createElement('a');
                    view_button.href = img_route;
                    view_button.innerHTML = 'View';
                    view_button.target = '_blank';

                    // Un botón para borrar la imagen
                    let delete_button = document.createElement('a');
                    delete_button.href = '#';
                    delete_button.innerHTML = 'Delete';
                    delete_button.classList.add('delete-button');

                    // Un input hidden para guardar el valor actual de la imagen (la ruta)
                    let hidden_input = createFileInput(true, true, img_route);

                    // Meter todos los elementos al contenedor general
                    image_container.appendChild(view_button);
                    image_container.appendChild(image);
                    image_container.appendChild(delete_button);
                    image_container.appendChild(hidden_input);

                    // Y meter el contenedor general dentro del contenedor padre de la columna de imagen
                    parent.appendChild(image_container);

                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Timeout para darle tiempo a crear todos los elementos antes de trabajar nuestro script personalizado
    setTimeout(() => {
        createImageColumns();
    }, 1000);

    // Listener con event delegation para eventos de nuevo archivo en input
    document.addEventListener("change", function(e) {

        // Obtener el dummy input 
        let current_dummy = e.target.closest('[data-dummy="true"]');

        if (current_dummy) { // Verificación de existencia por la delegación de eventos

            // Obtenemos el td
            let closest_td_element = current_dummy.closest('td');

            // Obtenemos el dataset de index como control para que la imagen se acomode en el index que le corresponde y se añada en orden en el array de archivos
            let index = closest_td_element.dataset.index;
            current_dummy.name = "item.image[" + --index + "]";

            // Añadimos clases y atributos por defecto de Backpack
            current_dummy.setAttribute('data-cell-name', 'item.image');
            current_dummy.classList.add('form-control');
            current_dummy.classList.add('form-control-sm');
            current_dummy.nextElementSibling.remove();
        }
    });

    // Listener para eventos de eliminación de imagenes
    document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        // Obtener el botón actual
        let current_delete_button = e.target.closest('.delete-button');

        if (current_delete_button) { // Verificación por la delegación de eventos
            e.preventDefault();

            // Creamos dos input, para controlar la data
            let input = createFileInput(false, false);
            let input_hidden = createFileInput(true, true);

            // Removemos todo lo relacionado a la imagen que ya estaba guardada
            let div_container = current_delete_button.parentElement;
            let parent_container = div_container.parentElement;
            div_container.remove();

            // Añadimos los inputs al contenedor padre de la columna
            parent_container.appendChild(input);
            parent_container.appendChild(input_hidden);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Ahora lo que falta es la manipulación de los archivos dentro de los métodos `store()` y `update()` según corresponda, el mismo código funciona en ambos:

```js
// $variants es un array que contempla dos tipos de valores diferentes:
// 1. string que puede contener la ruta completa de una imagen, indicando que fue previamente guardada y no modificada en este request o 'NA' indicando que se eliminó
// 2. Un objeto de la clase UploadedFile que indicaría que es una nueva imagen que se quiere guardar en este request
// Los campos se llaman "item.image[]" pero no estoy seguro el por qué funciona llamando el nombre como "item_image"
$variants = $this->crud->getRequest()->item_image;

// Si no estáa vacío
if (!empty($variants)) {

    // Crear array de paths
    $image_paths = [];

    // Make path variants' array
    foreach ($variants as $variant) {
        // Si es string, guarda la ruta tal cual
        // Si no es string (O sea un objeto UploadedFile), lo guardas como prefieras, yo uso un archivo personalizado, solo hay que retornar la URL completa para guardarla
        $image_paths[] = is_string($variant) ? $variant : FileHandler::saveFile($variant, 'product/variants', false, true);
    }

    // Obtenemos el contenido del campo table que en mi caso se llama cookware_variants y lo convertimos a array
    $variants_field = json_decode($this->crud->getRequest()->cookware_variants, true);
    foreach ($image_paths as $key => $path) {

        // Como $image_paths y $variants_field están preparados para que tengan el mismo número de elementos
        // Sincronizamos los valores usando la $key
        $variants_field[$key]['image'] = $path;
    }

    // Modificamos el campo table (cookware_variants) y le mandamos un json con el array que acabamos de crear
    $this->crud->getRequest()->request->add(['cookware_variants' => json_encode($variants_field)]);
}
```

Y listo, la tabla ahora soporta archivos (en mi caso imágenes), su visualización previa y su edición.

El código, especialmente JS, tiene oportunidad de mejoras, pero ya no le quise mover porque ya funcionaba como quería.

Answer (score 1):

La forma en la que se envían los datos de un formulario que incluye campos de tipo file es diferente a la de los campos de tipo text. Los campos de tipo file se envían en un array dentro del objeto $_FILES en lugar del objeto $_POST que contiene los datos de los campos de tipo text.

Para acceder a los datos enviados a través de un campo de tipo file en Laravel, puedes utilizar la función request()->file(). Esta función te devuelve una instancia de la clase Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile, la cual tiene métodos para acceder a la información del archivo subido, como su nombre, tamaño y ubicación temporal en el servidor.

Por ejemplo, si tu formulario incluye un campo de tipo file llamado image, puedes acceder a ese archivo subido en tu controlador de la siguiente manera:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $image = $request->file('image');
    // Aquí puedes hacer algo con el archivo subido, como
    // moverlo a una ubicación permanente en el servidor
}
```

Es importante tener en cuenta que, para poder acceder a los datos de un campo de tipo file en Laravel, el atributo enctype del formulario HTML debe ser configurado como multipart/form-data. Por ejemplo:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ...
</form>
```

Si estás utilizando Backpack For Laravel, es posible que tengas que agregar esta configuración manualmente a tu formulario. Por ejemplo, si estás utilizando la plantilla create.blade.php de Backpack para generar el formulario de creación de un registro, puedes agregar el atributo enctype a la etiqueta form de la siguiente manera:

```
@section('content')
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        ...
    </form>
@endsection
```

Espero que esta información te ayude a resolver tu problema.